# Converting SVG to PNG with ImageMagic ignores fill pattern url

Tags: php, svg, imagick, imagemagick-convert

I am using PHP's Imagick class to convert an SVG to PNG.

The conversion succeeds but seems to ignore any fill patterns. Here is my code:

```
<?php

$svg = <<<SVG
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<svg>
    <defs>
        <pattern id="myPattern" x="0" y="0" width="20" height="20" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
            <rect width="20" height="20" fill="#ffffff" /> 
            <circle cx="10" cy="10" r="5" stroke="#0000bb" fill="#dd8d8d" /> 
        </pattern>
    </defs>
    <text y="100%"
        stroke="#ff0000"
        fill="url('#myPattern')"
        font-size="40pt">
        Hello <tspan style="font-style: italic">SVG</tspan> world!
    </text>
</svg>
SVG;

try{

    $image = new Imagick();
    $image->setBackgroundColor(new ImagickPixel('transparent'));
    $image->readImageBlob( $svg );
    $image->setImageFormat('png32');
    $image->setImageCompressionQuality(100);

    file_put_contents('text-fill-example.png', $image);
}
catch(ImagickException $e){
    error_log($e);
}
```

In the above example, the letters should contain a dotted pattern. If you open the above svg code as a file in Inkscape, the pattern shows correctly. Also if you embed the svg code into html it shows the pattern correctly in modern browsers.

The pattern is also ignored if I try to convert from the command line:

```
$ convert -verbose text-fill-example.svg text-fill-example.png 
text-fill-example.svg SVG 358x36 358x36+0+0 16-bit DirectClass 433B 0.020u 0:00.030
text-fill-example.svg=>text-fill-example.png SVG 358x36 358x36+0+0 16-bit PseudoClass 256c 8.19KB 0.010u 0:00.009

$ convert --version
Version: ImageMagick 6.7.7-10 2014-03-06 Q16 http://www.imagemagick.org
Copyright: Copyright (C) 1999-2012 ImageMagick Studio LLC
Features: OpenMP
```

Does anyone know anything about this?

Comment: My question is probably related to this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35632706/imagemagick-not-applying-svg-filters-while-converting-to-png . Perhaps something to do with not following the `url('')` anchors?

Comment: Update: I'm currently reading up on SVG IRIs: `https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/linking.html`. I have tried to also include the xlink namespace. `xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"` Trying out different variations of syntax...

Comment: You would probably be better off asking at https://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out my SVG code was not entirely valid. I used the [W3C validator](https://validator.w3.org) to end up with some markup that is 100% valid and now it works:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" >
    <defs>
        <pattern id="myPattern" x="0" y="0" width="20" height="20" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
            <rect width="20" height="20" fill="#ffffff" /> 
            <circle cx="10" cy="10" r="5" stroke="#0000bb" fill="#dd8d8d" /> 
        </pattern>
    </defs>
    <text y="100%"
        stroke="#ff0000"
        fill="url(#myPattern)"
        font-size="40pt">
        Hello <tspan style="font-style: italic">SVG</tspan> world!
    </text>
</svg>
```

Comment: For others running into this post, I found that the original SVG through the command line with `convert -verbose -background none MSVG:so.svg -resize 640x640 out.png`  gave: `must specify image size`.. the miminum changes I needed were to add `width="620mm" height="640mm"` to the `<svg>` element, and remove the single quote chars from the `fill`, i.e. `fill="url(#myPattern)"`.  To get a non-blank output image, I also needed `viewBox="0 0 200 100"` on the `<svg>` element. (edit: these dimensions are from my project and not perfect for this sample)